# Cannot reconnect to x11vnc

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, remmina, x11vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry OS 64 bit and have installed x11vnc on it for remote access. I am using Remmina on the client side on my laptop running Debian 11. To make sure x11vnc is running after reboot or shutdown I have created a .desktop object in /etc/xdg/autostart/whatever.desktop on the Pi which in turn is set to execute a shell script which just runs "x11vnc" to start x11vnc. This works as intended. I can shutdown or reboot the Pi and I connect via Remmina just fine, however if connect to the Pi, then close the session in Remmina and then try to reconnect I always get "Unable to connect to VNC server". Seems strange that it works initially, and always the second time I try to connect I get unable to connect. Any inputs? Anyone?

Comment: Before asking random people on the internet, check your servers logs. They will contain far more information about your system than a random stranger could pull out of his nose...

Comment: Instead of adding the fix as a comment, consider writing an answer with the solution to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Running `x11vnc -reopen -forever` on the server fixed it for me.

That way you can reconnect as many times as you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answer surely could be improved, it did however restored my VNC! Thanks!!